# Schema.ini file location

Tags: c#, csv

I have created some code that works for me using OLE Jet to load a CSV file. I use the schema file to specify delimiter characters that are not the default comma.

The problem I am having is that the schema.ini file appears to have to be placed in same folder as the source CSV. This is fine for a static location but I want to allow the user to browse to any folder to load a CSV file.

Where else can I place the schema.ini file in a scenario like this. I do not want to modify the registry in case it impacts other applications and from my research Jet does not allow the delimiter to specified in connection string.

Is there any way I can build this into the application?

Comment: Cant you copy or move your Schema.INI to the user selected directory?

Comment: Can't you copy your user selected csv to the folder where you keep the schema.ini?

Comment: @Disaffected I ideally dont want the user to see the schema.ini file, JNevill thanks this is feasible, I could use a folder in the apps directory for this. I was hoping there would be a way to embed the schema.ini into the context of the application though.

Comment: There are a great CSV libraries that you would not need a Schema at all.